# XMLWriter formatting when appending to existing XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlwriter, xmltextwriter

I've got an existing XML file. New content is added to it via `XmlWriter` (or `XmlTextWriter`, doesn't matter which as both exhibit the same behaviour).

**The problem:**
The new content is not formatted with indentation.

Sample output by `XmlWriter` with `Indent=true` and `IndentChars` set to space:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RootContext Type="ETSP">
<Root><Element1>1</Element1><Element2>2</Element2><Element3>3</Element3><Element4>4</Element4><Element5>5</Element5></Root></RootContext>
```

Using this sample code to create additional XML content adding it to the existing XML (`<RootContext Type="ETSP"> ...`):

```
        XElement srcTree = new XElement("Root",
            new XElement("Element1", 1),
            new XElement("Element2", 2),
            new XElement("Element3", 3),
            new XElement("Element4", 4),
            new XElement("Element5", 5));
```

The existing XML I'm appending to is read via `XmlTextReader`/`XElement.Load()`.

**Now:** *this* happens when creating a new XML - **using the same settings** - containing just the generated snippet from above:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
   <Element1>1</Element1>
   <Element2>2</Element2>
   <Element3>3</Element3>
   <Element4>4</Element4>
   <Element5>5</Element5>
</Root>
```

Great. Properly indented, formatted - just what I want.

**Now - how can I get the indented formatting when appending to existing XML content?**

Comment: I'm surprised you can append data at all. How about don't do that, read into XDocument, append to XDocument, write whole thing out with indentation?

Comment: Well - why not? Load XML using TextReader then you've got your document as `XElements`, voila.. I'll try using XDocument, thanks for the hint

Comment: Can you share the code that is actually doing the writing?

Comment: There's nothing here that anyone could use to reproduce your issue.  `Ident=true` is ignored when there is significant whitespace written, but it could be anything.  Add some code.  Though I'm inclined to agree with @JohnSaunders - there should be an easier way of doing this that doesn't involve using such low level APIs.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks - using `XDocument` directly works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW - using the approach suggested by John Saunders and going to `XDocument` works just fine.

The new content is appended to the existing document with the desired formatting.